# Compare 2 json files in php

Tags: php, json

I wish to compare 2 json files( a.json , b.json) in php .

Files a.json and b.json will have array of json in it .

Files a.json and b.json will have different  alignment but the json array data will remains same

Is there any libraries for the above.

can any on help me out on this ?

Comment: json_decode() them both into PHP arrays, then use PHP's array functions such as array_diff

Answer (score 2):

You can decode json array to a normal array using the PHP function `json_decode()` for both the files and then you can use `array_diff_key()`. This last function return the difference by key of the two arrays, if the result is empty then your files are equal.

```
$arrayA = json_decode(file_get_contents('path/to/a.json'),true);
$arrayB = json_decode(file_get_contents('path/to/b.json'),true);
$result = array_diff_key($arrayA,$arrayB);
if(empty($result)){
    //Same file
}else{
    //Differences occured
}
```

Let me know if it made the trick

Comment: both files has the json responses which was decoded as `json_decode($json,true)` will `array_diff_key()` accept file names as arguments ?

Comment: No you got to read the content with file_get_content(). I've just edited my answer

Comment: You have to do the array_diff both ways to be sure both source datasets are the same